# Dynamically inject objects to a variable at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to dynamically add classes to an already assigned variable at RunTime. Here is an example to illustrate:

```
export class Bar { }
export class Foo { }
export class Qux { }

export let Class = {
  FooClass : Foo,
  BarClass : Bar
};

export class ParentClass {
  public addToClass(className : string, classType : any) {
     Class.add(className, classType); // this obviously doesn't work but somethhing like this
  }
  public getClasses() {
     return Class;
  }
}
```

At RunTime i would like to call

```
ParentClass pc = new ParentClass();
ps.addToClass('QuxClass', Qux);
ps.getClasses(); // Should return {FooClass, BarClass, QuxClass}
```

I know this is possible with Map/Dictionary but i need to get it working for this object holder otherwise it'll require a complete refactor.

Comment: If you think of what you call a _class_ as what it actually is in JavaScript - an _object_, then you find that adding objects to other objects is quite normal in JavaScript. The approach you've taken is unusual, but it could be made to work.

Comment: replace `Class.add(className, classType)` with `Class[className] = classType`

Comment: Oh man is it that simple!!... Thanks. a lot Kharel! that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kharel for the solution!!

ref:
`replace Class.add(className, classType) with Class[className] = classType`